# Why does chutz laaretz pray for rain when Iraq needs it?

Tags: tefilla, chutz-laaretz, geshem-tal-ruach

Tain tal is supposed to be a prayer for rain for local areas. However, most of Europe and the U.S. needs it when Israel does. Babylonia needed it for late November because that's when the Tigris and Euphrates overflowed and irrigated fields. I was told that it can't be changed because the original psak, over 2000 years ago, was that chutz laaretz (when Bavel was the only primary community) would say it in Nov because that's when they needed it.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Indeed, the Rosh (quoted in Biur Halacha OC 117) says that in his opinion we should just go by the local climate like the OP asks - but his opinion was not accepted (I don't know why though)

Comment: This has been discussed from several different angles on this site. I can’t find the question I was thinking of, but this is one place: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13263/603. — see related questions to that one as well.